# 413 Payload Too Large on Django server

Tags: django, webserver, http-status-code-413

My team has been getting 413 errors whenever we try and upload large files to our Django back-end: `413 Payload too large`

We can't exactly pin down the maximum acceptable file size - it seems to vacillate in the 1-3MB range.

Things we have excluded:

- It's not a webserver configuration issue, because we're running the
  Django server locally (without a webserver)
- We believe it's not an app server configuration issue, because this happens on multiple app servers (`./manage.py runserver` and
  `daphne -p 8000 topknott.asgi:application`)
- It's not an issue with the field on the Django model, which looks
  normal: `photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)`

Can anyone spot what we're missing?

Comment: Do you have nginx in front of it?

Comment: No I don't - it's running locally on my machine. (`./manage.py runserver`)

Comment: I don't see any relevant hits for "413" in the Django codebase. Are you using a third-party file storage engine? In any case, try adjusting the [`FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size) setting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Django has a build in mechanism to prevent any suspicious activity.

In your settings.py file set the variable

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10*1024*1024  # your size limit in bytes
```

See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE

Answer (score 4):

If your team was/is using [Django Channels](https://pypi.org/project/channels/), there was a piece of code introduced in [`2.1.7`](https://github.com/django/channels/compare/2.1.6...2.1.7#diff-eced37f82f11e166dfa2ae477f64566167f52c6be5cb12aa452e3c797ce86ef2R125) causing an unintended 413 error (discussed [here](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1240)). This was fixed in [`2.3.0`](https://github.com/django/channels/compare/2.2.0...2.3.0#diff-eced37f82f11e166dfa2ae477f64566167f52c6be5cb12aa452e3c797ce86ef2L125), however.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know runserver or daphne will never return a 413. Looks like you have NGINX in front of the python server.

You can change the limit with client_max_body_size  in the server block in nginx.conf

```
    server {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm running the Django server locally on my machine. That means there's no webserver (no NGINX) in front of the Python server